# llvm not generation byte code properly

Tags: llvm

I've installed llvm 3.0 with llvm-gcc 4.6 on ubuntu 11.10. I'm trying to do the "example with llvm-gcc4" on http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#tutorial4

But here's what I get:

```
buse@buseZenbook:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

buse@buseZenbook:~$ llvm-gcc --version
gcc-4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

buse@buseZenbook:~$ llvm-gcc hello.c -o hello
Potential incompatible plugin version. GCC: 4.6. Expected: 4.6.1
Defines 'dragonegg_disable_version_check' as env variable to remove this warning
Please note that unexpected errors might occur.

buse@buseZenbook:~$ llvm-gcc -O3 -emit-llvm hello.c -c -o hello.bc
Potential incompatible plugin version. GCC: 4.6. Expected: 4.6.1
Defines 'dragonegg_disable_version_check' as env variable to remove this warning
Please note that unexpected errors might occur.

buse@buseZenbook:~$ ./hello
Hello World!

buse@buseZenbook:~$ lli hello.bc
lli: hello.bc:1:1: error: expected top-level entity
ELF>�@@
^
```

And hello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
printf("Hello World!\n");
return 0;
}
```

~
Any suggestions?

Comment: It tells you that you have dragonegg for 4.6 when you need dragonegg for 4.6.1. Also, from my experiences, clang is a much more sane solution...

Comment: there's no such thing as dragonegg for 4.6.1 yet. Is there? I need downgrading then eh? But, I thought that since both 4.6.x it wouldn't be a problem. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: @Buse Naz, have you built dragonegg manually or installed some weird binary package instead?

Comment: I installed many weird packages :) I built only clang from source. Well, the thing is, llvm-gcc should not be dragonEgg. As far as I read from forums..etc there's a bug. I managed to install llvm-2.7 on ubuntu 11.10 using deb packages. But no luck whatsoever with llvm-3.0. (the newest version with stable packages is release 2.7 as far as I can see)

Comment: @Buse Naz If you have clang, use it. Its magical. Seriously. Really the only benefit of GCC is that you might get slightly faster (_might_) generated code... but you lack the amazing error messages of clang

Comment: I'm going to use llvm to do stuff on CFG/DFG and do some analyses on the code. I'm new to llvm, will clang do any good for me? (Haven't been through all that doc yet)

Comment: @BuseNaz Have you solved it somehow??? I have the same experience right now.

Comment: @James, yepp I solved it by installing llvm+clang from source. Packags did not work for me. Folow the steps here http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html. I advise to skip cmake part. I causes a lot of problems with xcode (I use ubuntu+eclipse but I've seen people experiencing it hence I skipped).

Comment: Any you don't need dragonegg anyway. By the way, if you separate object and source directories make sure that you put all your sources in source directory and add build directory to your path.